# Generate all way of arranging a given number of elements

Tags: ruby, combinations

I would like to generate all possible way of arranging of a certain number of elements `number_of_elements`. For now, I just want to print every possibility up to the possibility `upto`.

*Edit*: Say `number_of_elements` is 3, then I want all possible ways of arranging `0`, `1` and `2`. **A number can appear 0 or many times, and order is important**. So `0` != `00` != `01` != `10` != `11`.

For example, all_combinations(3, 14) should print:

```
0
1
2
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
000 # updated. I originally put 100 here by mistake.
001
...
```

I tried this:

```
def all_combinations(number_of_elements, upto)
  0.upto upto do |n|
    puts n.to_s(number_of_elements)
  end
end

all_combinations(3, 10)
```

My idea is to get all integers, convert them to base `number_of_elements` and interpret that number as the possibilities.
It almost works, except that I am missing some elements.

(This is the output I get with the code above) :

```
0
1
2
   # 00 missing
   # 01 missing
   # 02 missing
10
11
12
20
21
22
   # 0.. elements missing
100
101
...
```

Any idea or other simple method to get those?

Comment: What is unclear ? I'd be glad to explain.

Comment: In what sense is the combination `10` counted as different from `01`?

Comment: I want all possible ways to arrange those 3 characters. One character can appear many times. So `00`is different than `01` which is different than `10` which is different than `11`. Maybe there is a word for this way of enumerating possibilities...

Comment: You mean you want permutations? If so, why did you write combinations?

Comment: Yes, and an element can appear many times.

Comment: If so, why did you write combinations?

Comment: I don't have a better word. I'll update my post.

Comment: What happens when `number_of_elements` is greater than 36?

Comment: @sawa Then I would need an other way of representing my elements (with  arrays eg `[0], [1], ... [35], [0, 0], [0, 1], ...`). But in my case, `number_of_elements` is 3 or 4, so that's not an issue.

Comment: In the actual result, you wrote elements are missing between `22` and `100`, but in the expected result, you also have them missing.

Comment: This is *an* interesting question, despite the fact that you have accumulated two downvotes and a vote to close.  Yes, you mixed up the difference between permutations and combinations, and yes, the wording could have been clearer, but I don't see how anyone could be unable to figure out what you want in view of the example you gave. I don't like seeing downvotes just because the t's are not all crossed.  In future, I suggest you address comments asking for clarification by editing your question, rather than trying to explain in a comment.  You can still do that here, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578555/spreadsheet-rails-convert-column-index-into-character-sequence/13579195#13579195). The following is a slight modification of my answer there.

```
class Numeric
  def sequence b
    s, q = "", self
    (q, r = (q - 1).divmod(b)) && s.prepend(r.to_s) until q.zero?
    s
  end
end

def foo(number_of_elements, upto)
  1.upto upto do |n|
    puts n.sequence(number_of_elements)
  end
end

foo(3, 14)
```

Result:

```
0
1
2
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
000
001
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Array#repeated_permuation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation):

```
def all_combinations(nbr, upto)
  (1..nbr).each_with_object([]) do |n, arr|
    arr.concat(('0'...nbr.to_s).to_a
                               .repeated_permutation(n)
                               .to_a) if arr.size < upto
  end.first(upto).each { |e| puts e.join }
end

all_combinations(3, 14)
0
1
2
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
000
001
```

If `number_of_elements` is large, this approach has the disadvantage that a substantial number of permutations may be added to the array `arr`, but not used.  One alternative is to create an enumerator object which can be used to enumerate repeated permutations using [Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek), enumerating exactly `upto` values.  I showed how to do that for `permutation` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588375/ruby-how-do-you-set-an-enumerators-state/23603070#23603070) and explained how it would be even easier for `repeated_permutation`.

Comment: Nice solution. I'll keep @sawa answer as accepted because I think it's a little more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest way to attack this is--unfortunately, if you're not versed in recursion--with a recursive method.

You want to try every possible digit in every possible place, basically.

```
def all_combinations(s, number_of_elements, upto)
  if number_of_elements < 1
    puts s
    return
  end
  0.upto upto - 1 do |n|
    all_combinations(s + n.to_s, number_of_elements - 1, upto)
  end
end
all_combinations("", 3, 10)
```

The premise is that, wherever you've gotten to in the process (`s`; imagine it's `12`), you want to append all possible digits to it and continue.  But, we don't want to go forever, and each digit we place gets us closer, so reduce `number_of_elements`; when `number_of_elements` is zero, we have nothing else to do, so it's time to print.

A couple of issues:
 - `upto` doesn't know how big it is.  If you call `all_combinations("", 3, 500)`, you'll get badly-formed strings.
 - As mentioned, if you're just learning programming, recursion might not be the best place to dive in.
 - Likewise, if this is for homework and you haven't *covered* recursion, this would be a good sign that you're asking random people on the Internet for help, which may not result in an ideal grade.

With those caveats, though, I think this is the most straightforward approach.  Everything else that comes to mind requires keeping track of positions and recent outputs manually, which...*ick*.

Comment: If `number_of_elements` is 3, I only want `0, 1, and 2`'s. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. `number_of_elements` is not my sequence length.  Also, I always want the sequences of all sizes. In my question, I have shown what the output should be like (see `For example, all_combinations(3, 14) should print`). Yours starts with 001, 002, 003, 004...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise way of doing it using `repeated_permutations`:

```
def all_combinations(number_of_elements, upto)
  elements = (0...number_of_elements).map(&:to_s)
  combinations = (1..1.0/0).lazy.flat_map do |i|
    elements.repeated_permutation(i).map do |permutation|
       permutation.join
    end
  end
  puts combinations.take(upto).to_a
end

all_combinations(3, 14)
0
1
2
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
000
001
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing this, using [String#to_i](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) and [Fixnum#to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s), each with the argument `base` (which defaults to 10) set equal to the "number of elements":

```
def all_combinations(n_elements, upto)
  s = '10'
  upto.times.with_object([]) do |_,arr|
    arr << s
    candidate = (s.to_i(n_elements)+1).to_s(3)
    (candidate = '1'+'0' * s.size) unless candidate[0] == '1'
    s = candidate
  end.map { |str| str[1..-1] }
end

all_combinations(3, 15)
  #=> ["0",   "1",   "2",
  #   "00",  "01",  "02",
  #   "10",  "11",  "12",
  #   "20",  "21",  "22",
  #  "000", "001", "002"]
```